# IsNull returns TRUE when inserting empty (NOT NULL) strings in a LONG VARCHAR field (SQL Anywhere)

Tags: sql, delphi, varchar, firedac, sql-null

Delphi 10.3.2 enterprise, database ASA (SQL Anywhere 17.0.9.4913).

I have this table

```sql
CREATE TABLE string_null(
    lo_key integer NOT NULL DEFAULT AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    str_short char(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    str_long long varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT '');
```

and I want to insert records using FireDAC `TFDConnection` and `TFDQuery` components.

```pascal
qry.Insert;
```

If I assign non-empty strings, everything works properly.

```pascal
qry.FindField('str_short').Asstring := 'ABC';
qry.FindField('str_long').Asstring := 'XYZ';
```

If I insert a record using empty strings (empty, not null!)

```pascal
qry.FindField('str_short').Asstring := '';  // IsNull is FALSE, ok
qry.FindField('str_long').Asstring := '';   // IsNull becomes TRUE (wrong!)
```

the `IsNull` property on the **LONG VARCHAR field** returns TRUE even if it has been assigned a NOT NULL value (the empty string), while the **short field** behavior is correct.

(*The property `FormatOptions.StrsEmpty2Null` for both the connection and the query is FALSE*).

Furthermore, when I execute the `Post()` method, Delphi raises the exception on the `LONG VARCHAR` field:

> Field 'str_long' must have a value

If I set

```pascal
qry.FindField('str_long').Required := FALSE;
qry.Post;
```

the record is successful inserted in the database, with empty strings values.

**To make short a long story: if I insert a record with empty string values in a `LONG VARCHAR` field, the `IsNull` property returns a wrong value and I have to assign `Required := False` in order to get the `INSERT` operation executed.**

In this small demonstrative application I try to insert

- a record with NOT EMPTY strings (and everything works properly)
- a record with EMPTY strings.

[image: Test application output]

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.Intf,
  FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.Phys.ASA, FireDAC.Phys.ASADef, FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait,
  FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt, Data.DB, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  FireDAC.Phys.SQLite, FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteDef, FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs, FireDAC.Phys.ODBCBase, FireDAC.Comp.UI;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    conn: TFDConnection;
    qry: TFDQuery;
    memo: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure exec_insert(str_value : string);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  LONG_FIELD = 'str_long';
  SHORT_FIELD = 'str_short';

procedure TForm1.exec_insert(str_value : string);

  procedure msg(s : string);
  begin
    memo.Text := memo.Text + s + #13#10
  end;

begin
  msg('======================');
  msg('INSERT VALUE = "' + str_value + '"');
  try
    qry.Insert;

    if qry.FindField(SHORT_FIELD).IsNull then msg('BEFORE assign SHORT field is NULL')
    else msg('BEFORE assign SHORT field is NOT NULL');
    if qry.FindField(LONG_FIELD).IsNull then msg('BEFORE assign LONG field is NULL')
    else msg('BEFORE assign LONG field is NOT NULL');
    msg('');

    qry.FindField(SHORT_FIELD).AsString := str_value;
    qry.FindField(LONG_FIELD).Asstring := str_value;

    if qry.FindField(SHORT_FIELD).IsNull then msg('AFTER assign SHORT field is NULL')
    else msg('AFTER assign SHORT field is NOT NULL');
    if qry.FindField(LONG_FIELD).IsNull then msg('AFTER assign LONG field is NULL')
    else msg('AFTER assign LONG field is NOT NULL');

    //qry.FindField(LONG_FIELD).Required := FALSE;
    qry.Post
  except
    on e: Exception do msg('EXCEPTION: ' + e.message)
  end;
  msg('')
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  s : string;
begin
  conn.params.Text := 'Database=jolly'#$D#$A'User_Name=jop'#$D#$A'Password=jpw'#$D#$A'Server=jolly'#$D#$A'DriverID=ASA'#$D#$A;
  conn.FormatOptions.StrsEmpty2Null := FALSE;
  conn.Connected := TRUE;

  qry.FormatOptions.StrsEmpty2Null := FALSE;
  qry.SQL.Text := 'select * from string_null';
  qry.UpdateOptions.RequestLive := TRUE;
  qry.Active := TRUE;

  exec_insert('ABC');
  exec_insert('')
end;

end.
```

```dfm
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 299
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignSize = (
    635
    299)
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object memo: TMemo
    Left = 120
    Top = 8
    Width = 273
    Height = 283
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akBottom]
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object conn: TFDConnection
    Left = 28
    Top = 12
  end
  object qry: TFDQuery
    Connection = conn
    Left = 28
    Top = 64
  end
end
```

```pascal
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

I have not tested the behavior with other databases.

Comment: Your fields are defined as `NOT NULL`, so by definition `IsNull` should NEVER return True for them.  If it is, that is a bug.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I am not sure if that still holds true, when you call _qry.Insert_ before. After an _Insert_ usually all fields are NULL, aren't they?

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's true, but however I am free to call Clear method for every field -- but the POST will raise an exception.
My problem is the ISNULL is TRUE even if I assign a empty string value (not null).

(it's a pleasure to speak to you, I am a Redemption customer :-) )

Comment: I would still consider this a bug, since an empty string and a null string are two different things. [File a bug report with Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: @UweRaabe actually after the INSERT the fields are NULL. My problem is that the long varchar field is null even after I have assigned a value

Comment: I'm not familiar of what protocol does FireDac use when connecting to SQL Anywhere database but if it uses `TDS protocol` then it is possible that your database is configured to always return NUL for empty strings [tds_empty_string_is_null option ](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbadmin/tds-empty-string-alphabetical-dboptions.html). And some more infromation on NUL values in SQL Anywhere databases [NULL value ](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/nulls.html). Hope this infromation will help you find solution

Comment: Most Delphi data providers behave like this for BLOB fields.

Comment: @SilverWarior thank you but I don't think you are right because the issue appears only on `long varchar` fields. With _short_ string fields (i.e. `char(100)` ) everything works properly.
Moreover, FireDAC has explicit options to save empty strings as NULL values (`FormatOptions.StrsEmpty2Null`) but the issue does not depend from these options.

Comment: @Brian that's true, and in old days of BDE I have been using streams to read/write long varchar fields (as blob fields).
But - if possible - I would prefer to use ASSTRING to read/write `long varchar` fields.

Comment: @Feacio Your `str_short` will never be NULL as it is declared as fixed length string with size of 100 characters in your database, or in other words fixed sized field which are a part of specific data record. This means that it will always contain those 100 characters whether they contain your string or are just filled with space characters. ...

Comment: ... But your `str_long` fields don't have fixed size but instead they are determined based on their contents. These fields are not part of database directly but instead database records holds a reference to different part of the database that is used for storing dynamically sized data fields. And here the mentioned setting come in place as it defines about how are dynamic sized string stored in the database when they are empty.

Comment: @SilverWarior IMHO the problem (bug?) is in Delphi/FireDAC, not in the database.
I don't care how the database internally handles variable size fields, the point is that I like `asString` and `isNull` as they are simple and intuitive ways to read/write `string fields`, and that the behaviour of these functions with `long varchar` fields is inconsistent.
(And however fixed size field `str_short` can be `NULL` if I declare it `char(100) NULL`)

Comment: @Feacio Are you sure the bug is in FireDac? Have you tired accessing to your database using some different program that can check to see if certain field is nul? Also the documentation that I linked specify that you need to hcange only one database property to control how it handles empty strings. Have you tried changing that property to see if you are still getting the same results?